# ADFS 3.0 sign on page is not accessible using FQDN or IP but accessible using localhost.

Tags: adfs

I am trying to access ADFS 3.0 sign on page using server name or ip address but not able to brows . If I brows by using localhost instead ip or FQDN its working .
Can anybody tell me what are the possibilities of not able to browsing using ip or FQDN ?

There are solution like IIS setting but ADFS 3.0 no need of IIS.

Comment: I have a similar issue, I found that turning off IE Protected Mode in Server Manager helped to some extent, but the only way I can access the idpinitiatedsignon page locally now is as follows: 127.0.0.1 - NO, localhost - YES, FQDN - NO, IP - NO, Alternative DNS A-record - YES

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and it was due to the fact that I had used an invalid DNS name for 'Federation Service Name' when configuring the ADFS role.  After I removed the role (just fixing it didn't seem to make a difference), and added the role again, and putting the FQDN under 'Federation Service Name' while going through the configuration wizard.